# Apply Same Smoke Settings to Other Objects?

Tags: rendering, animation, smoke-simulation

I am using more than one smoke domain.  I create a new mesh, and then I add quick smoke.  My previous smoke domain is all set up with the settings I want.  Is there a way I can select both of them and apply the smoke settings of my finished smoke domain to my new one?
Thanks!

Comment: give it a try and report back the results.

Comment: I was asking if there was a way to.  I don't know how.

Comment: delete the second domain and duplicate the first one (Shift +D)

Answer (score 1):

Once you've set the second object as smoke inflow.

Delete the second smoke domain.

Duplicate the existing somke domain, bring it over the second object.

Then you need to delete the cache simulation on the second domain, and re-cache a new one.

[image]

When you cache Smoke (and other simulations) blender creates VBD files, that control the voxels for simulations. For multiple simulations, those have to be unique, to each domain.

Comment: when I do that, it changes the shape of all of the fires to the one I just cached.

Comment: That is why you need to delete the cache.

Comment: is there a difference between freeing data and deleting cache?

Comment: try it and see.

Comment: I already did free data and free noise.  When I baked the cache, all of them turned to the same shape.

Comment: When you cache Smoke (and other simulations) blender creates VBD files, that control the voxels for simulations. For multiple simulations, those have to be unique, to each domain.

Comment: oh, so I need to change the cache folder for each one so they are different. Thanks!